# How to evaluate BSplineFunction

Tags: splines

I have the following code to plot value of a bspline curve but it doesn't evaluate when I specify weights and knots and I'm not sure what's going wrong, the `weights` and `knots` vectors have the correct length (and if I change them I get an error) but for `f` I end up with a function that doesn't evaluate.

```
knots = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
points = {{0,0},{1/2,1},{1,1/4},{3/2,1},{2,0}};
weights = {1,1,1,1,1};
degree= 3;
f = BSplineFunction[points,SplineDegree->degree, SplineKnots->knots,SplineWeights->weights]
g = BSplineFunction[points,SplineDegree->degree]
g[0]
f[0]
```

Here's a screenshot of my output using Mathematica 10.3 on Windows:

[image]

Comment: It seems to not like your knots. `knots={0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}` works.  I note however the corresponding `BSplineCurve` works fine with your knots.

Comment: Ahh, it's annoying :) Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: No, the knots can not be just any sequence with the right length. It must fulfill specific conditions. Try for instance `knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, .5, 1, 1, 1, 1};`

Comment: Usually an admissible B-spline has the extreme knots repeated according to the degree of the spline. In the case of @george's knot sequence, you have a multiplicity of 4 in the first and last knots, corresponding to a cubic B-spline.

Comment: If memory serves the multiplicity is only required if you want the curve to pass through the end control points. Note `BSplineCurve` works without the multiplicity, (and does not hit the end points).

Comment: Hmm, something ain't right; if I use the explicit construction in terms of `BSplineBasis[]`, it works nicely. Something indeed is wrong with `BSplineFunction[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the B-spline curve:

$$
\overset{\rightharpoonup }{C}(u)=\sum _{i=0}^n N_{i,p}(u) \overset{\rightharpoonup }{P}_i
\text{    }\qquad
(a\leq u\leq b)
$$

where, $P_i$ is the control point, the $N_ {i, p} (u)$ are the $p$th - degree B-spline basis functions defined on the non-periodic (and non-uniform) knot vector:

$\{\underbrace {a,\cdots ,a}_{p+1},u_{p+1},\cdots u_{m-p-1},\underbrace {b,\cdots,b}_{p+1}\}$

Here, $m=n+p+1$ and the domain of curve is $[u_p,u_{n}]$

For your example

```
knots = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
points = {{0,0},{1/2,1},{1,1/4},{3/2,1},{2,0}};
weights = {1,1,1,1,1};
degree= 3;

f = BSplineFunction[points, SplineDegree -> degree, 
                    SplineKnots -> knots, SplineWeights -> weights]
```

So the spline function domain is $[3,5]$, you can verify it via the below code:

```
GraphicsColumn[
  {ParametricPlot[f[u], {u, 3, 5}], 
   Graphics[
    {BSplineCurve[points, SplineDegree -> degree, 
                  SplineKnots -> knots, SplineWeights -> Automatic]}]}]
```

[image]

Owing to the *built-in* `BSplineFunction[]` using the default domain $[0,1]$ to generate the spline icon, so `f` will lost the spline **icon** like this:

[image]

Normalize the `knots` to $[0,1]$,

```
BSplineFunction[
  points, SplineDegree -> degree, 
  SplineKnots -> {-(3/2), -1, -(1/2), 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2, 5/2}, 
  SplineWeights -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Also, I think you mean that the domain of the curve is $[u_p, u_{n+1}]$. See [this link](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-open.html) for example, the Piegl and Tiller book isn't as explicit on that point

Comment: @mkm No, Piegl discussed that domain on page 152 in chapter 12: **Data exchange** of The NURBS Book.